# PyGObject: libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_ptr_array_copy

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk, pygtk, pygobject

In Python, when trying to import Gtk from gi.repository or when trying to use Matplotlib, I get the following error.

> Failed to load shared library 'libpango-1.0.so.0' referenced by the typelib: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_ptr_array_copy

I tried to verify that everythin is linked properly:

> $ objdump /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 -T | grep g_ptr_array_copy

> 0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000      g_ptr_array_copy

> $  objdump /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 -T | grep g_ptr_array_copy

> 00000000000205e0 g    DF .text    00000000000000ff  Base        g_ptr_array_copy

Which looks fine to me. But still the error persits.

Comment: Possibly relevant question: what OS/Distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm using Debian 10 (testing) and Python 3.